# ES6 funciones flecha recorrer un array

Tags: array, es6

pregunta:
como mostrar los elementos de un arreglo con funciones flecha?

entiendo que dado un array con elementos, le paso el array como parametro, pero lo que no entiendo, es que debe ir en el cuerpo de la fncion?

se puede hacer esto con este tipo de funciones?
Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las funciones flecha son simplemente atajos a funciones asignables o callbacks para mantener el contexto en el cual son llamadas sin hacer un `.bind` explícito. Por ejemplo:

```
class A {
  constructor () {
    this.name = 'Letra A';
  }

  foo () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log(this.name);
    }, 3000);
  }
}

new A().foo();
```

El ejemplo anterior muestra una de las problemáticas gracias a las cuales se propuso esta nueva notación para funciones. El código anterior imprime `undefined` porque `this` se refiere a `window` y no a `A`.

Lo anterior se soluciona en ES5 de la siguiente manera:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  console.log(this.name);
}.bind(this), 3000);
```

A partir de ES6, con la llegada de las funciones flecha, la solución es más sencilla:

```
setTimeout(() => console.log(this.name), 3000);
```

---

Respondiendo a tu pregunta, la manera de iterar sobre un arreglo es la misma usando ES6:

```js
let names = ['John', 'Martha', 'Leslie'];

names.forEach(name => console.log(name));
```

Comment: estimado, muchas gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: tengo una duda.. en el caso por ejemplo que quisiera mostrar solamente 2 elementos.. en este caso, la funcion flecha no me sirve? es decir, sirve solo para funciones que son mas bien sencillas como lo es el foreach? como se podria hacer para un for comun desde n hasta n+m ?

Comment: En caso quieras mostrar un subconjunto del array, lo más viable es usar un for normal. Las funciones flecha, repito, son simplemente funciones, las mismas que vienes conociendo desde tiempos remotos. Lo único que cambia es la sintaxis en ellas para permitirte poder acceder al contexto superior cuando se usa la función como callback.

Comment: A lo que me refiero con "contexto superior" es al ejemplo que puse de la clase `A`. Volviendo a tu pregunta, si quieres mostrar solo ciertos valores usando `forEach` aún es posible; lo que tienes que hacer es hacer un `return` en los índices que quieres obviar. Por ejemplo: `names.forEach((name, i) => if (i === 1) { return; } console.log(name));`. El código anterior muestra "John" y "Leslie" solamente.

Comment: @LuisGabrielFabres `var filtro = ['a', 2, 'c', 4].filter((v,i) => i < 2);` ... donde `i` equivale al índice.

Comment: @Ricky, la función `filter` se usa para filtrar un array; en ese caso, se tendría **que volver a recorrer** `filtro`. La función `filter` sirve para extraer un conjunto de valores de un conjunto mayor, no para evitar ciertos índices de un array.

Comment: excelente maestro.. muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

### ES6

```js
['a', 2, 'c', 4].forEach(v => console.log(v));
```

---

Si quisieras evaluarlo en **ES5** sería equivalente a:

```js
['a', 2, 'c', 4].forEach(function(v) {
  return console.log(v);
});
```

Comment: gracias por las respuestas